# displaying 3 images in a row with text underneath in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display 3 images in a row with a title, some text underneath the title and a button. I have tried doing this in bootstrap only to get the text moving all over the place. This seems like the only way I could get the text to stay put, but now as you can see my images are stacked on top of each other rather than next to each other. Any help would be appreciated!

```
 <section class="part2">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="text-center">
                <img alt="" class="resize-image" id="image1" src="/wp-content/themes/creativeforces/images/kid2.jpg"> 
                <p>Teach</p>
                <img alt="" class="resize-image" id="image2" src="/wp-content/themes/creativeforces/images/kid2.jpg">
                <p>Read</p>
                 <img alt="" class="resize-image" id="image3" src="/wp-content/themes/creativeforces/images/kid2.jpg">
                <p>Play</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

this is what it looks like now
[image]

i am trying to get it to look something like this
[image]

Comment: Try using their grid system: 

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: I tried, but it wasn't allowing me to put any text underneath the image. In order for it to work I had to put each line of text in its own row and then when I resize the browser the text got all cluttered. I want the text to stay under each image no matter the screen size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add grids to your rows. This should work

```html
 <section class="part2">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                <img alt="" class="resize-image center-block" id="image1" src="/wp-content/themes/creativeforces/images/kid2.jpg" /> 
                <p class="text-center">Teach</p></div>
                <div class="col-md-4"><img alt="" class="resize-image center-block" id="image2" src="/wp-content/themes/creativeforces/images/kid2.jpg" />
                <p class="text-center">Read</p></div>
                 <div class="col-md-4"><img alt="" class="resize-image center-block" id="image3" src="/wp-content/themes/creativeforces/images/kid2.jpg" />
                <p class="text-center">Play</p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this example. You need to use bootstrap grid classes like "col-md-x" where x is number from 1 to 12.

```
<section class="part2">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
            <img alt="" class="resize-image" id="image2" src="/wp-content/themes/creativeforces/images/kid2.jpg">
            <p>Read</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
            <img alt="" class="resize-image" id="image1" src="/wp-content/themes/creativeforces/images/kid2.jpg"> 
            <p>Teach</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
             <img alt="" class="resize-image" id="image3" src="/wp-content/themes/creativeforces/images/kid2.jpg">
            <p>Play</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```