# centering text under images flask

Tags: html, css

Hi I am very new to html so I am having trouble understanding the examples online. 
I want text either aligned under my images or to the right of the image. (see picture for reference) [image]

Here is my current html code

```
<!-- reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35755237/displaying-3-images-in-a-row-with-text-underneath-in-bootstrap -->
<!-- https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_center.asp -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

</head>
<body>
  <style>
img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
</style>
  <section class="part2">
       <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
           <div class="text-center">
             {% for element in range(size) %}
               <img alt="" class="resize-image" src=" {{url_for('send_image', filename=image_names[element])}}" style="width:20%">
               <p>{{test[element]}}</p>
               {% endfor %}
           </div>
       </div>
       </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use "text-align: right;" in your css. If you haven't learned css yet, you absolutely should. Html is only meant for the structure of your site, while css is for the styling.

Comment: I tired doing something similar from this  links explanation https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_align.asp but it messed up with the photos

Comment: The align attribute of <img> is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead. While images are inline objects, you can still use "text-align" in css as stated in the answer above.